# How do I pass an integer into the pthread_create function from argv? (C)

Tags: c, casting, pthreads, argv

For this program I pass in numbers through the command line and then have a multithreaded program that takes each argument, calculates its factors, then prints them.  I know c++, but I'm rough with c and can't seem to get the casting down correctly for this program.  Specifically when I pass the argument into the thread_create and cast it to an integer.  The code I have below compiles, but the value after the cast is always a 0.  How do I cast the char value to a void* then to an integer?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<pthread.h>

    #define MAX_ARRAY (17)

    void *thread_func(void *);

    int factors[MAX_ARRAY];

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

            pthread_t thread_handle[argc];
            int i;
            int g;

            // Create Children Threads
            for ( i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
                    pthread_create(&thread_handle[i], NULL, thread_func, &argv[i + 1]);
            }

            // Rejoin Threads
            for ( i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
                    pthread_join(thread_handle[i], NULL);

                    // Print Factors Here
                    printf("%d: ", atoi(argv[i]));
                    for ( g = 0; g < MAX_ARRAY; g++ ) {
                            printf("%d, ", factors[g]);
                    }

                    printf("\n");

                    for ( g = 0; g < MAX_ARRAY; g++ ) {
                            factors[g] = 0;
                    }
            }
            return 0;
    }

    void *thread_func(void *data) {
            int n = atoi(data); 
            int x;
            int v;

            printf("Number to factor is: %d\n", n);

            for ( x = 1; x <= n; ++x ) {
                    if (n%x == 0)
                            factors[v++] = x;
            }
            return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any casts in your code or any reason to think you should need them.

Comment: In the thread_func I have to dereference the value passed in, and that value is a void pointer.  I have to cast it from a void* to an integer* or something I can dereference.

Comment: @user3208991: No, the pointer points to the character string from the command line. You just need to pass that to `atoi` (like you're doing) to interpret the string as a decimal number.

Comment: The problems in your code are unrelated. `v` is used uninitialized, and `factors` is global and accessed by all threads without any synchronization. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there...

Comment: I'm trying to have each thread access that same array and insert its factors into it.  Once one thread has done so, and joined, it'll print its factors from the array, then when the next thread runs it overwrites the previous thread's numbers and does the same thing.

Comment: @user3208991 If multiple threads are accessing a single array, `factors`, you need to put a mutex lock before accessing it or you will have deadlocks and memory corruption.

Comment: And if you do that, you might as well not have threads to begin with.

Comment: I'd like to allocate the array to the heap from main, but I'm not sure how to access the pointer from the function when I'm already passing in another value.

Comment: There would be multiple ways to do it, one of the easier solution being using a global variable, you can also provide a configuration structure to create thread routine than just a pointer to argument

Comment: Referencing argv[argc] is not UB, since it's guaranteed to be NULL, but calling atoi(NULL) is certainly UB, so it's not what you want to do. In other words, you need to fix your loops. (Hint: there are `argc - 1` command line arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each thread uses the same array for the factors, without any synchronization. But if each thread had to get a lock for the array before running, they would in effect all run in sequence which would defeat the purpose of threading.

Incidentally, argv[0] is the program name, which you should skip.

What you should do is have a different factor array for each thread, so that they can work independently without interference. You should also do all the display in the main thread, to control the order in which things are printed.

Since it is probably best to display the factors in order, you should first create all the threads, then join all of them, then finally display the results.

There were also a few small errors here and there like off by one errors or uninitialized variables.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY   17

typedef struct {
    int factors[MAX_ARRAY];
    int n;
} thread_data;

void * thread_func (void *);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = argc - 1;
    pthread_t thread_handle[n];
    thread_data thread_data_table[n];
    int i;

    // Create Children Threads
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        thread_data_table[i].n = atoi (argv[i + 1]);
        pthread_create(&thread_handle[i], NULL, thread_func,
                       &thread_data_table[i]);
    }

    // Join Threads
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        pthread_join(thread_handle[i], NULL);
    }

    // Print Factors
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int j;

        printf("%d: ", thread_data_table[i].n);
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_ARRAY; j++ ) {
            int x = thread_data_table[i].factors[j];
            if (x == 0) {
                break;
            }
            printf("%d, ", x);
        }
        printf("\n");        
    }
    return 0;
}

void * thread_func (void *data)
{
    thread_data *p = (thread_data*)data;
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= p->n; ++i ) {
        if (p->n % i == 0) {
            if (count == MAX_ARRAY) {
                break;
            }
            p->factors[count++] = i;
        }
    }
    if (count < MAX_ARRAY) {
        p->factors[count] = 0;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I apologize for my messy code.  I misunderstood how the threads actually run in comparison to one another.  Is it possible to achieve the same results by allocating an array on each thread (freeing it after it is joined)?